# Ruby Load multiple scripts from directory with foreach loop

Tags: ruby

I'm using a loop to load and execute Ruby scripts in a directory. At the moment the script will load the script, but how do I execute it when the only reference to it is the filename in the form of a string?

```
Dir.foreach('tests') do |item|
   next if item == '.' or item == '..'   #removes extra "." or ".."
   load dirname + '/' +  item            #successfully loads the script
   if  item                              # the scripts return true/false
     numberPassed+=1
   else
     numberFailed+=1
     failed.push(item)
   end
   numberTested+=1
end
```

For some reason I'm getting 2 Passed, but it never actually runs the scripts "item" represents.

**EDIT:** here is an example of a script that would need to be loaded. They all follow this format:

```
require "watir-webdriver"

class TestScript


  puts 'Testing etc etc"...'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
browser.goto "webpage.htm"
browser.text_field(:name => "j_username").set "username"
browser.text_field(:name => "j_password").set "password"
browser.link(:id, "watSubmitLogin").click

browser.wait

browser.link(:id=> 'watCommDir').fire_event("onmouseover")
browser.link(:id=> 'watAddFi').click
browser.wait

...


browser.link(:href, "javascript: submitForm();").click

browser.wait

if browser.text.include?( 'The user already Exists')
  puts 'Passed'
  browser.close
    return true
else
  puts 'Failed'
  browser.close
   return false
end

end
```

I need to somehow tell the main script whether the sub-scripts pass or fail so I can keep track of how many pass/fail/error/total and create a report of all the tests that failed.

Comment: What kind of test scripts do you have? Can you post an example? For me the approach to run your tests this way looks strange, let's see what you got.

Comment: Edited. I want to make adding tests as easy as adding a script to the directory that returns true or false. The testing will be automated to run all tests scripts and generate a report daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are doing acceptance testing with Watir and try to do custom test results reporting.

I would recommend to use existing test runners to run all your tests and build custom output formatter for your needs. Existing test runners already solve a lot of issues you will encounter during creation of your own test runner (like how to run tests from specified folder, how to identify failing/successful test etc).

One of the commmon test runners for acceptance tests in Ruby community is [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/). Another good alternative is [RSpec](http://rspec.info/). Both these libraries support custom formatters:

- In RSpec you would need to subclass [RSpec::Core::Formatters::BaseFormatter](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/2.8.0/RSpec/Core/Formatters/BaseFormatter).
- In Cucumber you would need to implement class with methods specified in [this documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters).

---

If you want to stay with the current simple implementation, here is one possible approach that is inpired by ruby Regexps: Inside the test set global variable, e.g. `$test_succeeded` (like `$~`, `$&` etc. global variables generated by ruby regular expressions) and then examine this value in your test runner.

In tests

```
if browser.text.include?( 'The user already Exists')
  puts 'Passed'
  browser.close
  $test_succeeded = true
# ...
```

In tests runner

```
Dir.foreach('tests') do |item|
  next if item == '.' or item == '..'   #removes extra "." or ".."
  load dirname + '/' +  item            #successfully loads the script
  if $test_succeeded
# ...
```

If you have problems running the script then I can recommend to define special method to run tests (similar to RSpec approach):

```
def test
    test_res = yield # call test
    $test_results ||= {} 
    $test_results << test_res # and store its result in arra of test results
end
```

Then your tests will look like:

```
require 'file_with_test_method'
require 'watir-webdriver'

test do 
    # your test code

    browser.text.include?( 'The user already Exists') # last expression in the block will be the test result
end
```

Comment: I'm using Watir. I don't want to use a test runner because everything is already pretty simple. I just need to know if all the tests ran successfully, and if not which ones failed. Also b) I don't want to waste time how to learn it when what I have will work fine. How do I run each script and return whether or not it passed?

Comment: @unmuse, I updated my answer with alternative possible solution to your issue

Comment: @unmuse, Also added small example on how you can run your tests